# Is there official documentation about upgrading your iOS app's minimum requirements?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

There are a couple of questions addressing what happens when you upgrade the minimum iOS of an app and there are still users on older iOS versions. 
The answers don't seem to agree with each other. Some say that the user sees no update, but others say the user does see that there's an update available, but that she should update their iOS first.

To get rid of uncertainty, I was wondering if anyone knows if there's official documentation from Apple about this and where to find it?

**update**

The question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48377/when-an-iphone-app-is-updated-and-the-minimum-required-ios-increases-what-happe?rq=1) is an example of the question being answered, but only for the case where the device is actually capable of updating to the new iOS. The answer is also enlightening, but fails to provide any official Apple documentation on it.
This documentation might not exist (I couldn't find it), but I thought it worthwhile to throw the question out there.

Comment: Are you refering to questions asked on this site? Can you add links to them so that whoever tries to answer your question can do it based on existing information and avoid further contractions?

Comment: Added a question that answers part of this question.

Comment: Are you asking from the point of view of an application user or a developer?

Comment: The developer's point of view. I want to be able to tell my clients "X will happen if we upgrade the minimum requirements of your app." This works for devices that can be updated, but I have no answer for their followup question: "Yeah, but we have a lot of people that still use the app on their old iPhone 3G/iPad. Will they see an update they can never reach?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, not yet at least. Whenever my apps need an upgrade to their minimum requirements due to a new version of iOS, I always have gotten an email explaining everything.